# How to check date between 2 dates (not SQL)

Tags: c#, winforms, datetime

In my WinForm, user input in textbox date as '210514' or '231113 (in ddmmyy format)
Assume today date = 291014 (29-Oct-14).
Using Visual Studio 2010 C# 4.0.
PC date time setting: GMT +08:00 dd-MMM-yy.

CodeBehind:

```
// Split the input string into YYMMDD format and set it to a date object
DateTime inputDate = new DateTime(Convert.ToInt32(input.Substring(4, 2)), Convert.ToInt32(input.Substring(2, 2)), Convert.ToInt32(input.Substring(0, 2)));
```

// the WinForm allows user to input date not earlier than 2 years before today date and not more than 1 months from today date too.

```
DateTime minDate = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-24);
DateTime maxDate = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(1);
```

I tried many methods but none works (I have checked many threads/forums also).

```
//Method 1
if(inputDate >= minDate && inputDate <= maxDate)
    return true

//Method 2: B return true but A ***always*** return false, Why??
if (inputDate >= minDate)
    A = true;

if (inputDate <= maxDate)
    B = true;

//Method 3: B return true but A ***always*** return false, Why??
if ((DateTime.Now - inputDate).Days >= (DateTime.Now - minDate).Days)
    A = true;

if (inputDate <= maxDate)
    B = true;
```

Comment: Firstly, I would suggest `DateTimePicker` controls rather than `TextBoxes`.  If you must use `TextBoxes` though, at least use `DateTime.TryParseExact` to validate and convert the `String` to a `DateTime`.

Comment: Hi jmcilhinney, our client insists to have textbox instead of datepicker because they wanted to key in the format of ddmmyy without to select using mouse.

Comment: Then, as I said, you should be using `DateTime.TryParseExact` to firstly validate the data, which could be anything in a `TextBox` and then convert the data to a `DateTime` value.

Comment: Why is there a need to use the DateTime.TryParseExact since I have already created a Date object from the input. All validations have been cleared

Comment: Because your code to convert the `String` to a `DateTime` is silly given that there exists a method specifically to do that.

Comment: Okay I take note of my silly approach. But why did A always evaluate to false then, when B is true?

Comment: As for your question, in method 2, `A` will only be `false` if `inputDate` is less than `minDate`.  Therefore, if `A` is ALWAYS `false` then `inputDate` is ALWAYS less than `minDate`.  If you think that should not be the case then you need to actually look at your data.

Comment: Can you provide a snapshot of debug data.

Comment: Imho, what is way more important: In your whole post I don't see a single question. What excatcly is you problem?

Comment: @jmcilhinney. Update: I have changed to what you suggested but it does not solve the problem. I have input my date as 261014 (which is 26-Oct-14) where the minDate is 29-Oct-12 and maxDate is 29-Nov-14. Of course i understood the logic that if A is always false, then the inputDate is always less than it, and B returns true. I placed a breakpoint and look at the watch. The 3 dates variables values are correct.

Comment: Aneesh Mohan, how do i provide the debug data to you?

Comment: Based on the code you've shown us, `A` will NOT be `false` if `inputDate` is not less than `minDate`.  You say `A` is ALWAYS `false` but you're wrong.  It's that simple.  You're just not testing it properly.

Comment: there is a method in DateTime that parses your string back to datetime try using the parse method instead of manual code.

Comment: @jadavparesh06, you're 25 minutes late with that partial advice.

Comment: @jmcilhinney That is Exactly why I posted and asked for help. It really puzzled me! I tested the similar code with PHP, VB.net and A evaluates to True. jadavparesh06, I have already changed it to the tryparse method. The reason for not using it was because of this unbelievable error I am encountering and I want to fall back to the caveman method. I remembered I encountered a VS bug when I was using VS 2002 back then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm posting this as an answer so I can post code.  I just did this:

```
DateTime inputDate;

if (DateTime.TryParseExact(this.textBox1.Text, "ddMMyy", null, DateTimeStyles.None, out inputDate))
{
    var minDate = DateTime.Today.AddYears(-2);
    var maxDate = DateTime.Today.AddMonths(1);
    var A = inputDate >= minDate;
    var B = inputDate <= maxDate;

    MessageBox.Show(string.Format("input: {1:d}{0}min: {2:d}{0}max: {3:d}{0}A: {4}{0}B: {5}",
                                  Environment.NewLine,
                                  inputDate,
                                  minDate,
                                  maxDate,
                                  A,
                                  B));
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Invalid input");
}
```

I entered "091014" in my `TextBox` and the message said that `A` was `true`.  Likewise for "101012" and "101014".  Unless something on your system is corrupt, it's not the code but rather it's you who's wrong.  Test that exact code and see if you get the same result.

Comment: Actually I wanted to do a simple app and put it up on my website for you guys to download and try. Your code works and I found the problem. By right, my codes *should* work. The difference is, I put minDate = DateTime.Now.AddMonths (-24). This is the bug. Strangely. When I changed to .AddYears (-2), every other methods worked.

Comment: I just changed my test code to use `DateTime.Today.AddMonths(-24)` and it still worked exactly as it should.  Either you did something else wrong or something was broken in your project.

Comment: Nevermind, for some reason VS just crashed while I was doodling the codes.

Answer (score 1):

Method A is correct, and you would have seen why it doesn't work if you use a debugger.

```
string input = "291014";
DateTime inputDate = new DateTime(
    Convert.ToInt32(input.Substring(4, 2)),
    Convert.ToInt32(input.Substring(2, 2)),
    Convert.ToInt32(input.Substring(0, 2)));

Console.WriteLine(inputDate.Year); // 14, oops
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.Year); // 2014
```

To fix it add 2000 to the year

```
DateTime inputDate = new DateTime(
    2000 + Convert.ToInt32(input.Substring(4, 2)),
    Convert.ToInt32(input.Substring(2, 2)),
    Convert.ToInt32(input.Substring(0, 2)));
```

Comment: Interesting. This is something for me to take note of. Thanks Dirk.